# Disable button if selected option equals something

Tags: angular

I have an table representing users. I would like to allow Administrators to change an user role by click a button next to combobox with new user role.

I was trying in manys way, but something is missing in my html code, to connect a button with selected value of combobox. 
Could you help me  ?   I have a little problem with understand how exactly binding working.

> this.keys = Object.keys(this.roles).filter(Number)

```
 <tr *ngFor="let oper of operaotrs">
          <td> {{oper.id }}</td>
          <td> {{oper.login }} </td>
          <td> {{oper.role}} </td>
          <td> <div>
            <md-select placeholder="New Role">
              <md-option  *ngFor="let key of keys"  [value]="key"> {{roles[key]}}</md-option>
            </md-select>
            <button md-raised-button [disabled]= "isDisabled(SOMETHING)" > PROCEED </button>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td> <button> DELETE </button> </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put a `[(ngModel)]` in your md-select.

Once you've done it, use `[disabled]="yourNgModel === 'the value you want'"`

**EDIT** You have to make your ngModel depending on your ngFor like so

```
 <tr *ngFor="let oper of operaotrs; let i = index">
          <td> {{oper.id }}</td>
          <td> {{oper.login }} </td>
          <td> {{oper.role}} </td>
          <td> <div>
            <md-select placeholder="New Role" [(ngModel)]="operators[i].yourPropertyYouWantToBind">
              <md-option  *ngFor="let key of keys"  [value]="key"> {{roles[key]}}</md-option>
            </md-select>
            <button md-raised-button [disabled]= "isDisabled(SOMETHING)" > PROCEED </button>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td> <button> DELETE </button> </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: I was trying with NgModel, but once it adding, it change the value for ALL  operators, and not only for one.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.View_ManageUsersComponent_1.currVal_0 [as   ->  in ngModel

Comment: In case you didn't see, you wrote `operaotrs` while my ngModel contains `operators`

Comment: yes.. you're right. But it still didnt work as I need. Now with change the value in combobox, the "role" in operator is changing too. I dont want it.  The role should be changed AFTER click PROCEED and reurn an correct answer from server

Comment: Then use temporary variables. I only have a bit of your code, I can't guess it like that.

Comment: when I met  operators[1].role it was changing  the role, but when I was met   operators[i].newproperty  it return "undefined"

Comment: Well, did you add that property to your objects ? Do you know how to use temporary variables at least ?

Comment: it #variable ??

Comment: ok..  it works with  operator[1].newproperty. Iseams that Angular add it.  The value is not really  an Enum value, but number,  but I was implement a function to  compare and it works